# entity framework - what approach to take on saving data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0, dbcontext

I am using the latest EF5 with a code-first approach. 
My repository is a non-static class.
The problem - if I want data to be updated correctly I can take one of two approaches:

1. Create one instance of the Repository and toss it around all over my application.
2. Do something like this when saving:

Example:

```
var foo = myDbContext.MyObjects
              .First(object => object.Id = idOfObjectIWantToSave)

foo.PropertyToUpdate = newValue;
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

What is the best approach to take? Making a static class for DAL is also possible, but I've read [on stackoverflow] it is not such a good idea.

Comment: What is wrong with the latter? People recommend against making a static class because the idea behind an EF Context is to perform a single unit of work by design, and thus is cheap to create.

Comment: @Steve B actually an assembly used by both types..

Comment: The context isn't just a repository. You need to use one context per unit of work, but you only need to pass it around for that time.

Comment: @John Saunders So I take you are suggesting the second approach?

Comment: More or less. You don't need or want to keep the context around for the life of the application. The lifetime of the context should span the unit of work. And it's not just about saving. You need to use the same context when fetching data that will later be used in saving.

Comment: @John Saunders
"You need to use the same context when fetching data that will   later be used in saving"

If I take the second approach that will no longer be necessary..

Comment: Sure will be if you use navigation properties at all, and modify linked entities.